# Emplois de « dans » et « à »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

> Le facteur porte des paquets dans la ferme.
>
> Le facteur porte des paquets à la ferme.

Quelle est la différence ? Les deux phrases sont-elles interchangeables ?

> Le facteur porte des paquets dans cette ferme lointaine.

Dans ce cas l'on peut remplacer *dans* par *à* ?

> Le facteur porte des paquets à cette ferme lointaine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Au TLFi, on déclare vieilli une acception de [*porter*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/porter) encore bien vivante au Québec (et peut-être aussi ailleurs), qui met ce verbe synonyme avec *apporter*.

Si donc on dit...

> Le facteur porte des paquets dans la ferme.

...on pourrait vouloir exprimer, ainsi que mentionné dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/30246/13100), que le facteur est dans la ferme en train de porter des paquets.

Mais on pourrait tout aussi bien penser qu’il est en direction de la ferme, y portant *(apportant)* des paquets. Les paquets seraient alors destinés à être reçus sur le terrain même de la ferme *(**dans** la ferme)*, et vraisemblablement donc passé la simple entrée ou limite habituelle de réception de marchandises diverses.

Ce n’est peut-être pas un français standard *(en fait, je n’en sais rien)*, mais ce serait la façon la plus naturelle et plausible d’imaginer l’action décrite. Le fait de dire qu’un facteur va et vient dans une ferme, portant des colis, représente selon moi une possibilité bien plus théorique qu’habituelle.

> Le facteur porte des paquets à la ferme.

Ainsi que mentionné dans la réponse liée ci-dessus, le facteur va livrer des paquets à la ferme. Il est probable que la livraison se fera directement au lieu de rencontre avec les travailleurs de la ferme, où en quelque lieu de réception habituel qu’on lui indiquera au besoin.

La distance de la ferme ne change guère l’interprétation.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse détaillée. En effet ce sont deux phrases que j'ai tirées du livre La nouvelle grammaire du français (Larouse, 1973; J. Dubois et R. Lagane.). Peut-être il faut que j'actualise un peu mes livres de grammaire:-)! Du coup je possède des grammaire plus récente mais je ne sais pas pourquoi je préfère les vieilles:-)!

Comment: @dimitris Je suis avec vous sur les anciennes ressources linguistiques, que je collectionne avec plaisir et aime à consulter pour voir en direct l'évolution temporelle des règles et tendances de la langue. Une grammaire récente pour vous ne serait sans doute pas un mauvais investissement (puisque le sujet vous intéresse): il s'en fait d'excellentes et très complètes aujourd'hui, plus qu'avant je crois. Mais ne vous séparez pas de vos vieux livres!

Answer (score 1):

> Le facteur porte des paquets dans la ferme

Veut dire que le facteur est dans la ferme, en train de porter des paquets.

> Le facteur porte des paquets à la ferme

Veut dire que le facteur va livrer des paquets à la ferme.